# What beautiful soup findall regex string to use?

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have links in HTML of the form

```
<a href="/downloadsServlet?docid=abc" target="_blank">Report 1</a>
<a href="/downloadsServlet?docid=ixyz" target="_blank">Fetch Report 2 </a>
```

I am able to get a list of links of the above form using BeautifulSoup

My code is as follows

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
listOfLinks = list(soup.findall('a'))
```

However, I want to find the links which have the word "Fetch" in the text referencing the link.

I tried the form

```
soup.findAll('a', re.compile(".*Fetch.*"))
```

But that is not working. How do I select only the tags a which have an href and the text portion has the word "Fetch" in it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A regex may be an overkill here, but it allows for possible extensions:

```
def criterion(tag):
  return tag.has_attr('href') and re.search('Fetch', tag.text)

soup.findAll(criterion)
# [<a href="/downloadsServlet?docid=ixyz" target="_blank">Fetch Report 2 </a>]
```

Comment: Great ! I redid it as a lambda function. Thanks !

Comment: Used soup.findAll(lambda tag: tag.has_attr('href') and re.search('Fetch', tag.text))

Answer (score 6):

```
import re
soup.findAll('a', text = re.compile("Fetch"))
```

you can use regex as filter, it will use `re.search` method to filter our the tag.

`text/string` are text value of the tag, `text = re.compile("Fetch")` means find the tag which text value contains 'Fetch'

[Document](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression)

and one more thing, use `find_all()` or `findAll()`, `findall()` is not a key word in bs4

Comment: This isn't working for me. It will only find an exact match of "Fetch"