# How to find Specific item in <script> using BS4 web scraping

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to get id in below script. Alsa

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = "https://www.beko.com.tr/cift-kapili-buzdolabi/b1-8459-smn-buzdolabi"
print(url)
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


id_all = soup.find_all('script')

print(id_all)

driver.close()

---------------output is more complex but I just want to get below 'id': '7291920212'------


 </script>, <script>
        dataLayer.push ({

            'ecommerce' : {

              'detail': {
                'actionField': {'list': ''},
                'products' : [
                  {
                    'name': 'B1 8459 SMN',
                    'id': '7291920212',
                    'brand': 'Beko',
                    'variant': 'Null',
                    'category': ''

                  }
                ]
              },
```

Comment: Try using `re` module like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41757995/5805827

Comment: you can retrieve this just with requests. Why bother with selenium?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `regex`.

For example:

```
import re

from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = "https://www.beko.com.tr/cift-kapili-buzdolabi/b1-8459-smn-buzdolabi"
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
print(re.search(r'content_ids:\["(\d+)"\]', str(soup.find_all('script')), re.S).group(1))

driver.close()
```

Output:

```
7291920212
```